# In ASP.NET MVC, is there a way I can check the if the users logged in to my application through a public network or company's LAN?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, networking, authorization

I am writing an ASP.NET MVC application. I have been asked to allow certain no. of users (no. varies from 10-100) to access my application from both public network and company's network but restrict other users (5 - 500) from accessing application from public network.

These restricted users can only access the application inside company's network. How can I achieve this?

For this, do I need to store I.P address of every user? But they can use other laptops or desktops to access the application.

Can I check the network user is using to access my application?

Answer (score 0):

> restricted users can only access the application inside company's
>   network

If your company have purchased some IP and use it on the network. You can whitelist them in your ASP.NET MVC Application. For example your company buy a range of IP. You can check the IP of Request is come under that range then yes it's IP of the company.

AFAIK There is no way to know if your user comes from a public network or a company network.